# SAPI rule enumeration

Tags: c++, sapi

I've been using the Microsoft Speech API (SAPI, 5.3) to add speech recognition support to my application (Windows, obviously, C++, Win8 SDK) and aside from a few hoop-jumps relating to loading grammar files it's working quite well.

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to enumerate rules from a grammar that was loaded from file (or if that's even possible).  Obviously, when you build the grammar manually/dynamically, you are creating the rules yourself.   However, there doesn't *appear* to be a way to enumerate the rules from a grammar that was loaded from file.  IspRecoGrammar::GetRule() seems to be the closest thing I could find to being able to query for a rule, but it is intended for retrieving a single, known rule (it requires either a rule name or id).

For the time being I'm simply parsing the XML myself and plucking out the rule names, but that's not really a complete solution; I need to support both XML *and* binary grammar config files, the latter of which sidesteps my current work-around.

Anyone with SAPI experience know how I might accomplish this?

Comment: What is the higher-level goal you're trying to achieve here?   (AKA - why do you think you need to enumerate SAPI rules?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Eric.  In short, I need to pre-validate other data I have against the rules of the loaded grammar(s).  This other data references the rules by name, so at load-time of this other data I want to validate that the grammar rules (names) the data references are in fact valid.

Comment: In addition to the aforementioned processing of the XML, I can (and have) gotten by simply not validating and then adding the rules to the "known set" as they are encountered via SAPI recognition callback, but that's not a very robust solution for catching data errors.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `IspRecoGrammar::GetRule()` would still do what you need.   Have a set of known good rule names, and when you load your other data, use `IspRecoGrammar::GetRule()` to validate the rule name if it's not in the set of known good names.   If it's valid, add it to the set.   (You could also have a set of known bad names, as well.)

Comment: Good suggestion, it hadn't occurred to me to go at it from that direction.  That would certainly address the problem at hand (pre-existing data validation).  Thinking forward, it may be the case that for we'd want to present a list of known rules for authoring said referencing data, which would put us back at square one insofar as rules enumeration.  I presume that, as far as you know, there's no way to enumerate rules?  My own fairly deep internet search didn't turn up anything or anyone attempting something similar.

Comment: @SBD I did some checking, and most of the grammar compilation work is done on the engine side of the SAPI interface; this means that any rule enumeration done during grammar compilation is being done in an internal matter, and there isn't any other client-side interface for rule enumeration.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it.  Obviously there hasn't been an articulated need for that to this point; perhaps future versions will provide the facility (it seems an easy enough thing to expose).  For now I'll go about validating as suggested and cross that other bridge when I get to it.  Thanks again.